# Why can only be questions marked as favourites?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bookmarks

I would find it rather useful if answers could also be marked as favourites.

As an example I would like to point to this question: [How to unpack a TFTP file with Firmware](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3228/how-to-unpack-a-tftp-file-with-firmware)

I have no idea what a TFTP is, but the answer is rather helpful for other problems as well. However, when I mark this question as a favourite, in a few months, when I would look for the tools mentioned in the answer, I sure wouldn't recognize this question as the one that would help me.

Comment: You could bookmark the _share_ link of an answer in your browser.

Comment: @kapep, yes of ocurse...